# Syntax error in Magento module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, error, blocks

I have created a new page in Magento as

http://istockphp.com/magento/adding-custom-page-to-the-customer-account-dashboard/

It is working fine in my local machine,But it returns an error in my live server when i try to load that page

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Istockphp_Customerpage_Block_C' (T_STRING) in 
/home/public_html/app/code/local/Istockphp/Customerpage/Block/Customer.php on line 1
```

Comment: Try to convert the file(s) to UNIX end of line format (because now it's Macintosh). If you have Notepad++ go to Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix Format. Or every other more advanced text editor or IDE has such option.

Comment: @michael Thanks,It is working,Could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad that it's working. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert the file(s) to UNIX end of line format (because now it's Macintosh).
If you have Notepad++ go to Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix Format. Or every other more advanced text editor or IDE has such option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the file(s) to UNIX end of line format (because now it's Macintosh). If you have Notepad++ go to Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix Format. Or every other more advanced text editor or IDE has such option

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when copying and pasting some Magento code from a web page. If I typed in the code manually the problem disappeared.